# Thread 1 filling a map every second and thread 2 persists entries every 60 seconds

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a scheduled executor pool of size 2. 1 thread fills a map every second and the second thread needs to take the data in the map and persist it to database and clear the data in the map. Whats the best way to share the map between the two threads so that no data is lost?

Comment: I think ConcurrentHashMap should be enough? But what issues you expect? What is confusing you?

Comment: While i am persisting, i don't want new entries to be added to the map. Lets say persist takes 2 seconds and during this time i don't want any changes to be done to the map by thread 1

Comment: Ok, just lock your map then while you are persisting, but it will definitely slows things down. I would better go with simple LinkedHashMap or some concurrent implementation of it ([ConcurrentLinkedHashMap](https://github.com/ben-manes/concurrentlinkedhashmap/blob/master/src/main/java/com/googlecode/concurrentlinkedhashmap/ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.java)), and keep track of the last entry that you took for persistence, so later you can grab only new records, but it depends on your requirements. Try to come up with some sample code, so we can understand your use case better.

Answer (score 0):

The `map` a shared resource,in order get the right result,we need to controlling multiple threads access `map`,There many method can we used:

- use a thread safe map like `ConcurrentHashMap`
- use a lock to ontrolling access to a shared resource by multiple threads
- change process to make operation serialization.

In the scene you describe i thisk use lock is easiest method,code like this:

```
private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
private Map<String, Object> dataSet = new HashMap<>();

private void fillDataSet(Map<String, Object> src) {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        dataSet.putAll(src);
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

private void dumpDataSet() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        // save data to db adn clear the data set
        db.saveData(dataSet);
        dataSet.clear();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Why `ConcurrentHashMap` is not a perfect solution for you ？

Thread2 need read the map and then write（clear）the map，but in `ConcurrentHashMap` retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may overlap with update operations (including put and remove).